# Selenium - Python: Everything works well with GUI but fails when run in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests

I´m new to stackoverflow and i´ve just been into software testing and this whole world for about a year but I am currently developing myself as a QA in a startup and i´ve been automating my test plan using Selenium with Python and Pytest.

Currently I have 359 tests that run perfectly on my computer when using the GUI but now my team has established a virtual machine to run them twice a day for what they have to run in headless mode and most of them fail.

When I run them headless on my computer they also fail, I don´t know why because it should work identically as far as i´m concerned.

I´ll be super gratefull if you guys can help me in making the necessary changes to make the automated suite run well in headless mode as well.

Thanks!

I just run them headless expecting them to pass as always but that didn´t go as I expected.

This is a bit of the code i´m using:

```py
class Test_CON_02_Coupons(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(60)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.vars = {}
        self.driver.get(CON_SELFSERVICE_URL)
```

Comment: What driver are you using? And are the tests downloading/exporting files, copy/pasting from web?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.